# How to submit an updated podspec to trunk when you're not the owner?

Tags: cocoapods

I have updated a `podspec` file from [CocoaPods Master Repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/) to use a more recent version of a library, updating some broken paths along the way.

I can `pod spec lint` and use it locally using:

```
pod 'LibraryX', :podspec => 'LibraryX.podspec.json'
```

However, since I'm not the owner of that Pod, I can not `pod trunk push` back my contribution.

What's the best way to propose a new podspec version for the trunk in that case?

Answer (score 0):

This is the purpose of the ownership model with trunk. To update a spec like this you should get in contact with the current maintainer. You could also submit a pull request with your change but before it is merged the current maintainer will have to ok it.

Comment: Currently you can find the owner of a podspec (for example if it is different from the maintainer of the corresponding project) only through the API. Example: https://trunk.cocoapods.org/api/v1/pods/libextobjc